# "Nash Style" Embedding Theorem for Connections

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections

The strong Whitney embedding theorem states that any smooth  (Hausdorff and second-countable) manifold can be smoothly embedded in Euclidean space. John Nash went on to show that any Riemannian manifold could be embedded into Euclidean space in such a way that the metric of the manifold would coincide with the standard dot product. This means that the Levi-Civita connection for the manifold maps to the standard connection. More generally, for a manifold $M$ with connection $\nabla$, when does there exist an embedding into Euclidean space such that the connection is mapped to the standard connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard connection is the Levi-Civita connection of the flat metric. So if you have an embedding such that the given connection is the (projection of the) flat connection then you can also induce a metric on the embedded manifold. Hence the given metric was already a Levi-Civita connection of a Riemannian metric on your manifold. Thus the question is whether a given connection is the Levi-Civita of some Riemannian metric. That was one of your earlier questions. Does that work?

Comment: Great. Sorry for inadvertently  asking the same question twice.

Comment: no problem. I even overlooked that it was you who asked the embedding previous question.

Comment: A link to the other question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54434/when-can-a-connection-induce-a-riemannian-metric-for-which-it-is-the-levi-civita