# Metric connection on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is locally Kähler but not globally Kähler

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds, connections

in a comment to this question [When can a Connection Induce a Riemannian Metric for which it is the Levi-Civita Connection?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54434/when-can-a-connection-induce-a-riemannian-metric-for-which-it-is-the-levi-civita)

Robert Bryant  mentions that it is possible to construct a metric connection on $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is locally Kähler, but not Kähler. I haven't been able to figure out how to construct such connection, can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: inside $SO(4)$ there are two copies of $U(2)$ whose product is $SO(4)$ see e.g Van Elfrinkhof's formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space.